# Why my Broadcast Receiver works while reboot?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I wrote a `BroadcastReceiver` which works perfectly but there is a problem, when I reboot my phone the `BroadcastReceiver` fires again.
My purpose is

It works only `BOOT_COMPLETED` statement when my phone restarts itself:

```
Toast.makeText(context,"Works",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"works _ second",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   

    }
```

My xml file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   <receiver android:name=".Alarmikinci">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Unclear. What is the problem ? At every boot your receiver is invoked. Thats ok. When else?

Comment: I tried your last words to my code. Seems like It works . How to works. My according to tuturial It works only  if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) { } . When restart. By the way I have 3  Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: What's the problem? The `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast is sent when the device's boot process has completed. This happens when you power on the phone (cold start) and also when you restart the phone (warm start). There is no difference.